# ROS Transport Layer - XML-RPC

Tags: ros, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is the XML-RPC/TCP transport layer used for "for node to node" topic communications?

AFAIK TCP/XML-RPC transport layer is used for the "node to master" interaction, but I have no idea about what happens in a "node to node" topic communication.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12720/ros-transport-layer---xml-rpc/) by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2982 on 2012-01-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Connection%20Header

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2012-01-23**:
Excelent. The transport mechanism for topics is a "custom ros binary format". This makes much more sense... thanks :-)